# bash while loop to explode variables from text file

Tags: bash, shell, while-loop

contents of origlist

```
$var1
$var4
$var3
$var2
```

contents of testparsher.sh

```
#!/bin/bash

var1="Smith^John"
var2="998877"
var3="member"
var4="12"
cat /dev/null > file.txt

filename=origlist

while read line; do

   echo $line >> file.txt

done < "$filename"
```

the file.txt I want is:

```
Smith^John
12
member
998877
```

the file.txt I'm getting is

```
$var1
$var4
$var3
$var2
```

So what's the syntax to get the loop to see the parsed text as the preloaded variables?

Thank you so much for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to use eval :

```
#!/bin/bash

var1="Smith^John"
var2="998877"
var3="member"
var4="12"
cat /dev/null > file.txt

filename=origlist

while read line; do
   eval echo $line >> file.txt
done < "$filename"
```

Comment: Thank you so much!!!!  All I had to do was add eval.  I can't believe I couldn't find this anywhere.  thank you

Comment: The use of `eval` here is *strongly* discouraged. Arbitrary code could be inserted into `origlist`, and this code will happily execute it.

Answer (score 2):

You can do this without 'eval' by using "indirect expansion" (see the Bash manual page for an explanation):

```
while read var || [[ $var ]] ; do
    varname=${var#$}
    printf '%s\n' "${!varname}"
done <"$filename" >file.txt
```

The '[[ $var ]]' is necessary to allow for an unterminated last line in the input file.

The '$' has to be removed from the variable name.  Does it need to be in the input file?

Use 'printf' instead of 'echo' in case the variable value begins with an 'echo option.

Comment: +1 This is much safer, as using `eval` introduces a *huge* security risk if the contents of the input file are modified. Using indirect parameter expansion, the worst that can happen is that unexpected input will cause a bad substitution error.

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for `eval`, but it comes with a lot of caveats.

Or perhaps you are looking for a here document.

```
cat <<____HERE >file.txt
$var1
$var4
$var3
$var2
____HERE
```

Comment: The here document won't help; I think `file.txt` exists prior to the variables it references being set.